# problem with routes in my menu, url is bad laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**I have a problem placing a route in my menu**

```
<div class="col">
    <a href="{{ url('/category/{slug}/contact')}}"><i style="color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer;" class="fas fa-id-badge"></i></a>
  </div>
```

the error is that it modifies the url

[image]

web.php:

```
Route::get('/category/{slug}/contact', [
'as'    => 'category-contact',
'uses'  => 'StoreController@categoryContact'
```

]);

help pls

Answer (score 1):

You can use route name and is more efficient

```
{{ route('category-contact', ['slug'=> $slug]) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the braces {} around `slug` in your route in html are being encoded. You need to remove those braces.

Or in case slug is a variable then change it to this

```
{{ url('/category/' . $slug . '/contact')}}
```